# Displaying multiple input from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to retrieve the values of "name" for an event from local storage from an array which contains multiple objects. After retrieving I want it to display under the month the event is held in, in a table calendar.
Here's my HTML codes:

```
 <table border="1" id="list" style="width:40%;margin:auto">
 <caption style="text-align:center; margin:5px; font-weight:bold; font-    size:30px; margin-bottom:10px">
 LIST OF EVENTS 
</caption>
<button id="show"onclick="addToCalendar();">Show</button>

<tr><th>Month</th><th>Events Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>January</td><td id="jan"></td></tr>
<tr><td>February</td><td id="feb"></td></tr>
<tr><td>March</td><td id="mar"></td></tr>
<tr><td>April</td><td id="apr"></td></tr>
<tr><td>May</td><td id="may"></td></tr>
<tr><td>June</td><td id="jun"></td></tr>
<tr><td>July</td><td id="july"></td></tr>
<tr><td>August</td><td id="aug"></td></tr>
<tr><td>September</td><td id="sept"></td></tr>
<tr><td>October</td><td id="oct"></td></tr>
<tr><td>November</td><td id="nov"></td></tr>
<tr><td>December</td><td id="dec"></td></tr>

</table>
```

My javascript codes:

```
function addToCalendar() {
     var index;

     for (index=0; index<events.length; ++index) {
         var entry=events[index];
         var d=entry.date;
         var date=new Date(d);

         var n=entry.name;

         var month = new Array();
            month[0] = "January";
            month[1] = "February";
            month[2] = "March";
            month[3] = "April";
            month[4] = "May";
            month[5] = "June";
            month[6] = "July";
            month[7] = "August";
            month[8] = "September";
            month[9] = "October";
            month[10] = "November";
            month[11] = "December";

         var m=month[date.getMonth()];
             if (m==month[0])
                {
                document.getElementById("jan").innerHTML=n;
                }

             if (m==month[1])
                {
                document.getElementById("feb").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[2])
                {
                document.getElementById("mar").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[3])
                {
                document.getElementById("apr").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[4])
                {
                document.getElementById("may").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[5])
                {
                document.getElementById("jun").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[6])
                {
                document.getElementById("july").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[7])
                {
                document.getElementById("aug").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[8])
                {
                document.getElementById("sept").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[9])
                {
                document.getElementById("oct").innerHTML=n;
                }
            if (m==month[10])
                {
                document.getElementById("nov").innerHTML=n;
                }
             if (m==month[11])
                {
                document.getElementById("dec").innerHTML=n;
                }

     }
 }
```

My question is, if there are two events that are held in say, January, how do I display both the events' name without one being replaced by the other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to your inner HTML. What you are currently doing is replacing it.

Do something like this:
  document.getElementById("jan").innerHTML += "Hello world"

You can also work with append child if you want to which might be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
document.getElementById("WhichEverMonth").innerHTML += n;
```

and consider using switch statements at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Thank you! I've added the switch statement and the code you gave. However now, it displays the name in a chunk. Eg. "FundraisingCharityExample". Is there a way I can separate these?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to append your additional events.  I would recommend refactoring your code to make it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
function addToCalendar(events) {
    var monthIds = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "july", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < events.length; ++index) {
        var entry = events[index];          
        var dateOfEvent = new Date(entry.date);
        var monthOfEvent = dateOfEvent.getMonth();

        var entryMarkup = entry.name + "<br />";
        var monthElement = document.getElementById(monthIds[monthOfEvent]);
        monthElement.innerHTML += entryMarkup;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but nothing will display when I run the codes

Comment: @F.F Here's a CodePen example of this script in action:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWENzQ  For the sake of simplicity in this example, I made your events array a property of the `window` object.  I didn't emulate any `localStorage` / JSON-parsing logic you may already be using.